# Emoji Connect Wall

Tags: pattern, wordplay, knowledge, connect-wall

Find the 4 groups of 4 Emojis connected by a common property.

The Emojis in each group may share a distinguishing characteristic in the name or in the appearance, or they may all relate to another English word. I made sure that visual similarities apply to all of the most common Emoji styles (Apple, Google, Twitter, etc.).

[image]

The table below shows the Unicode numbers of the Emojis used in the picture under their corresponding symbols (if supported by your browser).

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\huge \atop\tt{U+1F603}&\huge \atop\tt{U+1F3AB}&\huge \atop\tt{U+1F37A}&\huge \atop\tt{U+1F48D}\\\hline
\huge \atop\tt{U+1F4BA}&\huge \atop\tt{U+1F4D6}&\huge \atop\tt{U+1F46D}&\huge \atop\tt{U+1F513}\\\hline
\huge \atop\tt{U+1F40F}&\huge \atop\tt{U+1F43E}&\huge \atop\tt{U+1F4BF}&\huge \atop\tt{U+1F352}\\\hline
\huge \atop\tt{U+1F369}&\huge \atop\tt{U+1F4EC}&\huge \atop\tt{U+1F511}&\huge ⚔\atop\tt{U+2694}\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

Like in all connect wall puzzles, the purpose here is not finding arbitrarily many combinations of four that happen to share some common property, but finding *distinct* groups such that each element fits in exactly one group and no element is left out.

So far there have been a few brilliant guesses but no solution. I'll be posting hints if necessary.

#### Useful resources

- http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3Aemoji%3A%5D
- http://unicodey.com/emoji-data/table.htm

Comment: At first glance, this seems *way* too broad. But it still might not be - not sure yet.

Comment: I don t think it is any broader than the same game with words. The fact that there a 4 groups and they all need to match severely restricts 'random' solutions.

Comment: I m slightly puzzled/worried by the wordplay tag. @Goto Will the puzzle work nay in English? In this case, I believe it need to be stated.

Comment: @BmyGuest Good point. At least one of the Emojis is a homonym of another English word, and I guess the group would not fit so well if translated into some other languages. Well, that was a hint 

Comment: Can different Emojis be in different groups?

Comment: @Peanut Your question does not make sense. Did you mean if the *same* Emoji can be in more than one group?

Comment: Is the Mexican government paying for this wall?

Comment: @Goto0 Could you clarify in the posting whether the puzzle needs to be solved with the Emoji's as shown, *any* Emoji representation, or the representation by the Unicode? While it would possibly narrow down the puzzle to much (?) it would clarify whether *visual* aspects are important or not.

Comment: @BmyGuest Well, the representation in the image is Apple Color Emoji.

Comment: We've discussed this in mod chat and come to a consensus that it's too broad. There are visual characteristics, Unicode names, and representations on several different devices and websites - there are too many possible groups, and they're all valid - nothing makes any group stand out.

Comment: @GOTO0 Partly. My advice: let it be for a couple of days, then return and decide if the puzzle - if the broadness issues raised can be addressed - is still "working" as a puzzle. If so, edit and I vote for reopen. I think the puzzle has at least as much potential as the word-ones, but I can also see the mod's point considering the current state of the post. And I understand that emotions can "spoil" the fun of working on it. Get some distance - and then return, please!

Comment: I'm also a potential re-opener. My impression is that the solution depends more on the words and concepts behind the emojis rather than any visual details of a certain rendering style. If that is true, it might be enough to clean up the presentation of the puzzle.

Comment: I have a combination: sword, lock, key and ring - all made with metals

Comment: Is that a goat?

Comment: @DylanChensky In that case, you have forgotten the mailbox, because it's metal too.

Comment: I'm very, _very_ sure this is too broad as written, and as it's being answered. I could be wrong, but I'd be interested in discussing it on meta if people still want to reopen this question.

Comment: [Can you share with us if this is one of the correct answers?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/40606/9993)

Comment: @GOTO0 We still want to know the answer.

Answer (score 13):

Not complete...
Also just an idea...

> ,, , ⚔

Since

> They are all couples

Comment: You could the swords to complete it.

Comment: @Tom The swords were already there.

Answer (score 12):

One group could certainly be

> Emojis with "Open" in their text title

and would contain

> "Smiling face with **open** mouth"
>  "**Open** book"
>  "**Open** mailbox with raised flag"
>  "**Open** lock"

Comment: For me, the smile is "Grinning face with wide eyes", the book is just simply "Book", the mailbox is the same, and the lock is the same. This is from the emoji viewer on macOS Sierra developer preview 1.

Comment: @Peanut: These names are the official character names defined by the Unicode standard.

Answer (score 10):

Hmm... Here's another set:

> , , , and .

Explanation:

> They all are circles with holes in them.

Comment: Topologically, you'd also have to include the beer glass

Comment: Only if you took a section through it.  The rest have holes that go all the way through.

Comment: @MichaelKlein Also, the beer glass has a hole on the *top*.

Comment: @gtwebb: The hole all the way through the beer glass is the one formed by the handle and the glass, not the big beer cavity.

Comment: @user2357112 This then very much depends on whether we need to look at the Emoji's *as shown in the image* or by the Emoji's on a more general note. The symbol from the definition table does [not have a hole](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=1F37A).

Comment: To me, the set included in this answer looks the most correct. Can the OP tell us if this is correct or not?

Answer (score 5):

Another set (sadly not compatible with KeithN proposal):

> Edible:

Comment: Technically, I'd argue that the sheep is not immediately edible. But definitely more edible than other things.

Answer (score 3):

One more.. a bit of a simple answer

> They are all round

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Three groups I found:

> - : Items you read
> - : Things that start with a K (people are kids, lock is keylock, paws are K-9 paws)
> - : Food and beverages. (Kikiwa)

Comment: I think the 2nd one is a bit of a stretch

Comment: @yitzih You mean the last one of the 2nd group, right?

Comment: the whole 2nd group except the key (And maybe the children)

Comment: @yitzih Shhh! Don't say what the items are aloud! Also, how is the second item of the second group weird? Is it a word that does not exist?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος that one is generally called a padlock

Comment: @MoldovanHipster SHhh! So, why can't I call it like I have? *Generally* does not mean *the only way you can*.

Comment: I googled your name of the open lock, and it was like "did you mean (your nam of the locke withoit the c) probably sufficient proof that that term is never used... and even when Im not searchin the version with no c, I get no results for a open lock

Comment: @ev3commander Scroll down a bit; KEYLOK seems to be some sort of anti-piracy software.

Answer (score 1):

I'm stumped!

> How about "Computing related" as a category?  = RAM (Random Access Memory),  = Compact Disk or DVD, = Key (as in WEP Key?), and  = Ring (as in a web ring?)

I think the suggestions by KeithN and Dan Russell are pretty solid (more likely than mine) +1 and I can't for the life of me think of a connection between a ticket, a seat, beer, and a doughnut.  So I don't expect this to be right.

Comment: Android Donut O:)